# Jquery box animation change

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a box animation. It's working okay,
but I want to move the green box animation to the left. Sorry for my poor English.

**Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

```
$(".iphone").mouseover(function(){  
     $('#appstore').stop().animate({width:'276px'},{queue:false, duration:600,})  
          });  

            $(".iphone").mouseout(function(){  
         $('#appstore').stop().animate({width:'128px'},{queue:false, duration:600,})  

          });  
              }); 

                $(".android").mouseover(function(){  
           $('#play').stop().animate({width:'276px'},{queue:false, duration:600,})  

              });  

            $(".android").mouseout(function(){  
       $('#play').stop().animate({width:'128px'},{queue:false, duration:600,})  
   });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery is correct but `issue is in the css` you have absolute positioned elements and you used `margin-left` for that i just changed that to `right:0;` and animation for width came from `right to left.`

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/2/

check this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/5/

```
#play {
background:#97C024 url(../images/android.png) center left no-repeat;
position:absolute;
height:128px;
z-index:10;
width:128px;
right:0; // <----margin-left replced with right:0;
}
```

## note:

I just did the position `right` to `0`. You have to position it according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. I update a code again [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/4/)

Comment: check the updated answer and i have updated your latest fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/5/

Answer (score 0):

just add margin left attribute:

like here:

```
$(".android #play").hover(function () {
     $(this).stop().css({
         'z-index': 10000
     }).animate({
         width: 276,
             'margin-left': -276 + 128,
     }, {
         queue: false,
         duration: 600,
     })
 },

 function () {
     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: 128,
             'margin-left': '0',
             'z-index': 0
     }, {
         queue: false,
         duration: 600,
     })
 });
```

also note that i replaced `mouseover`/`mouseout` with one `hover`, and used `$(this)` to select correct element...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ggKrF/9/)

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. I update a code again [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ggKrF/4/)